# Add on a percentage to a variable value in Smarty 2 template

Tags: php, smarty, percentage, php-5.4, smarty2

I have assigned a variable in my Smarty 2 template.

```
{assign var="real_count" value="{$store_summary|@count}"}
{$real_count = settype ($real_count, 'integer')}
```

My goal is to add on 65% to the value of `$real_count`. With the data i'm working with I have a `$real_count` of 3, so the calculated value should be 4.95 (3 + 1.95).

I am attempting to use the `math` tag, however I am clearly missing something.

```
{math equation="x * y" x=$real_count y=0.65 format="%.2f"}
```

Comment: For very simple math, use: {math equation="x + 1" x=$index}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do this within the Smarty template, you can solve it like this (slightly simplified):

```
{assign var="real_count" value="3"}
{math equation="x + (x * y)" x=$real_count y=0.65 format="%.2f"}
```

However, I would usually advise against doing too much math and other logic in a template. In most use cases, it would be better to do the math within the application and then display the result within the template. Even the [Smarty manual](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.math.tpl) agrees with me:

> `math` is an expensive function in performance due to its use of the
>   php `eval()` function. Doing the math in PHP is much more efficient, so
>   whenever possible do the math calculations in the script and `assign()`
>   the results to the template. Definitely avoid repetitive `math`
>   function calls, eg within `section` loops.

Comment: You're right, I was taking the wrong approach. Thanks.